# What is the correct way to pass a JSON array to a Neo4j server based java class?

Tags: java, json, neo4j

I am hitting a wall trying to get data loaded in a JSON array successfully passed to a java class that runs over the Neo4j server.  My intent is to pass a list of entries from the client side to the server - nothing special here.  What I am doing is reading the entries on the client side, loading those entries into JSON objects and then putting each JSON object into a JSON array which is then to be passed to the server for further processing.

Here is a section of the client side code that loads the json object and array.  NOTE: the below is 
just the json related code stripped down w/o the try/catch and other items resident in the code.

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("field1", field1Value1);
    jsonObject.put("field2", field2Value1);
    jsonObject.put("field3", field3Value1);
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("field1", field1Value2);
    jsonObject.put("field2", field2Value2);
    jsonObject.put("field3", field3Value2);
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
```

Here is the client side code that handles the http post part of the equation - I believe this is ok.

```
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonArray.toString());
    stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "http://"server":7474/db/data/ext/serverSideClass/graphdb/processJSONData");
    post.setEntity(stringEntity);
    HTTPPostResponseResults httpResponse = new HTTPPostResponseResults();
    httpResponse.checkResponse(post);
```

Here is the method interface to the server side code and this is where I believe my problem lies.  I am thinking the parameter type needs to something other than JSONArray but am not sure what.

```
 @Name("processJSONData")
 @Description("process the data passed in.")
 @PluginTarget(GraphDatabaseService.class)
 public String processJSONData(@Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb,
        @Parameter(name = "jsonArray") JSONArray jsonArray) {
```

And... here is the error being thrown.

```
   "message" : "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map",
    "exception" : "BadInputException",
   "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.BadInputException",
   "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.JsonFormat.readMap(JsonFormat.java:92)",
   "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.readParameterList(RepresentationFormat.java:97)",
   "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension
```

The above should cover it for the items related to this posting.  If there is anything needed to clarify this please let me know and I'll provide it.  Thank you in advance.